# Making table width fit into text width

Tags: tables, margins

I'm using `p{}` format to adjust the width of a table.

I expected using `{p{0.1\textwidth}||p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}}` makes the table width smaller than the text width (1 > 0.1 + 0.2*4), but the result is not what I expect.

[image]

What might be wrong? Why the total width of the table is wider than text width?

This is the code.

```
\documentclass[oneside, openany, 10pt]{article}
%\documentclass[article, oneside, openany, 10pt]{memoir}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{1.0\textwidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{1.0\textwidth}{0.3mm}}

\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
  \centering
  {\Large \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}
  \HRule\par%
  \textit{\@author \hfill \@date}
  \par
}
\author{prosseek}
\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{table}[hbtp]
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.1\textwidth}||p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}}  
\hline
& Function & Pre conditions & Post conditions & Constraints \\
\hline\hline
R1 & An election official is assigned for each precinct & Precincts and
elections officials are created & Unique one on one mapping from an
election official to precinct & Before voting starts\\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Requirements before voting starts}
\label{eoRequirements}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Because you are not counting some other spaces (such as tabcolsep).  You could work around this by using either `tabulary` or `tabularx`... or simply considering the missing space (check the `array` [documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Mario's hint, I could use [tabulary](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabulary_package) to get this result.

[image]

```
\maketitle
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{1.0\textwidth}{C||L|L|L|L}
\hline
& Function & Pre conditions & Post conditions & Constraints \\
\hline\hline
R1 & An election official is assigned for each precinct & Precincts and
elections officials are created & Unique one on one mapping from an
election official to precinct & Before voting starts\\  \hline
\end{tabulary}
\caption{Requirements before voting starts}
\label{eoRequirements}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I think you should write it like `1.0*\textwidth`