# Lines Between Column Headings not Properly aligned using tabulary?

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabulary

Using the answer from prosseek here:

[Making table width fit into text width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135384/making-table-width-fit-into-text-width)

I was able to shrink my table to the textwidth. Unfortunately when I do this the lines between the column headers are no longer aligned with the lines below them?

How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}

I want a table that is the same width as the text I'm using tabulary and that has shrunk the table however the lines between the column headers are no longer properly aligned with the lines below then between the columns.


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\normalsize
\begin{table}[!h]
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{1.0\textwidth}{CCCC|C|CCCC|CC}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Parameter Estimates Subset 1 and 2} \\
\cline{1-11}
A     & L_{t-1} & S_{t-1} & C_{t-1}  & $\mu$ & Q&L_{t}& S_{t}  & C_{t}  & $\lambda$ & H   \\
\hline
L_t   & 1.031    & 0    & 0    & 6.02 & L_t  & 0.077  & 0      & 0      &  0.123&  0.017\\
  & ()       &      &      & ()   &      &(0.021) &        &        &(0.005)& (0.002)\\
S_t   & 0    & 0.910    & 0    & -0.02& S_t  & 0      & 0.720  & 0      &       &\\
  &      & 0.037)   &      & ()   &      &        & (0.059)&        &       & \\
C_t   & 0    & 0    & 0.681    & 0.28 &C_t   & 0      &  0     &  2.130 &       & \\
  &      &      & (0.070)  & ()   &      &        &        & (0.107)&       & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Parameter Estimates Subset 2 and 3} \\
\cline{1-11}
A     & L_{t-1} & S_{t-1} & C_{t-1}  & $\mu$ & Q&L_{t}& S_{t}  & C_{t}  & $\lambda$ & H   \\
\hline
L_t   & 1.031    & 0    & 0    & 6.02 & L_t  & 0.077  & 0      & 0      &  0.123&  0.017\\
  & ()       &      &      & ()   &      &(0.021) &        &        &(0.005)& (0.002)\\
S_t   & 0    & 0.910    & 0    & -0.02& S_t  & 0      & 0.720  & 0      &       &\\
  &      & 0.037)   &      & ()   &      &        & (0.059)&        &       & \\
C_t   & 0    & 0    & 0.681    & 0.28 &C_t   & 0      &  0     &  2.130 &       & \\
  &      &      & (0.070)  & ()   &      &        &        & (0.107)&       & \\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\caption{Results of the Maximum Likelihood Estimation for splits 1-4}
\label{table:param3}
\end{table}  
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.50}\normalsize


\end{document}
```

Comment: You have used the `_`  like (`S_t`) every where without math mode (i.e., `$..$`). Please enclose all of them with dollars `$` so that we need not do that job.

Answer (score 1):

I was lazy to put all those `$`s so I created a new column. But you have to use `$` when you write `L_t` etc.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}C<{$}}

\begin{document}

I want a table that is the same width as the text I'm using tabulary and that has shrunk the table however the lines between the column headers are no longer properly aligned with the lines below then between the columns.


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\normalsize
\begin{table}[!h]
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{1.0\textwidth}{MMMM|M|MMMM|MM}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Parameter Estimates Subset 1 and 2} \\
\cline{1-11}
A     & L_{t-1} & S_{t-1} & C_{t-1}  & \mu & Q&L_{t}& S_{t}  & C_{t}  & \lambda & H   \\
\hline
L_t   & 1.031    & 0    & 0    & 6.02 & L_t  & 0.077  & 0      & 0      &  0.123&  0.017\\
  & ()       &      &      & ()   &      &(0.021) &        &        &(0.005)& (0.002)\\
S_t   & 0    & 0.910    & 0    & -0.02& S_t  & 0      & 0.720  & 0      &       &\\
  &      & 0.037)   &      & ()   &      &        & (0.059)&        &       & \\
C_t   & 0    & 0    & 0.681    & 0.28 &C_t   & 0      &  0     &  2.130 &       & \\
  &      &      & (0.070)  & ()   &      &        &        & (0.107)&       & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Parameter Estimates Subset 2 and 3} \\
\cline{1-11}
A     & L_{t-1} & S_{t-1} & C_{t-1}  & \mu & Q&L_{t}& S_{t}  & C_{t}  & \lambda & H   \\
\hline
L_t   & 1.031    & 0    & 0    & 6.02 & L_t  & 0.077  & 0      & 0      &  0.123&  0.017\\
  & ()       &      &      & ()   &      &(0.021) &        &        &(0.005)& (0.002)\\
S_t   & 0    & 0.910    & 0    & -0.02& S_t  & 0      & 0.720  & 0      &       &\\
  &      & 0.037)   &      & ()   &      &        & (0.059)&        &       & \\
C_t   & 0    & 0    & 0.681    & 0.28 &C_t   & 0      &  0     &  2.130 &       & \\
  &      &      & (0.070)  & ()   &      &        &        & (0.107)&       & \\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\caption{Results of the Maximum Likelihood Estimation for splits 1-4}
\label{table:param3}
\end{table}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.50}\normalsize


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could employ a basic `tabular*` environment to get the job done, as there seems to be no need for the line-wrapping capabilities of the `tabulary` environment. The column type `C` is set to render its contents in math mode automatically.

By the way, it's not a very good idea to manipulate the low-level macro `\baselinestretch` directly. Instead, consider loading the `\setspace` package and issuing the instruction `\setstretch{1.5}` (or some other desired value). If nothing else, this method will relieve you from having to remember to set and reset the `\baselinestretch` macro before and after each `table` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,setspace,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}  % math-mode center-set column
\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.5}  % don't modify the low-level parameter '\baselinestretch' directly

I was able to shrink my table to the textwidth. Unfortunately when I do this the lines between the column headers are no longer aligned with the lines below them?

\begin{table}[!ht]
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}  % let "tabular*" env. determine the intercolumn widths
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{C@{\extracolsep{\fill}}CCC|C|CCCC|CC}
\hline
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{11}{l}{Parameter Estimates Subset 1 and 2} \\
\cline{1-11}
A & L_{t-1} & S_{t-1} & C_{t-1} & \mu & Q &L_{t}& S_{t} & C_{t} & \lambda & H \\
\hline
L_t   & 1.031    & 0    & 0    & 6.02 & L_t  & 0.077  & 0      & 0      &  0.123&  0.017\\
  & ()       &      &      & ()   &      &(0.021) &        &        &(0.005)& (0.002)\\
S_t   & 0    & 0.910    & 0    & -0.02& S_t  & 0      & 0.720  & 0      &       &\\
  &      & (0.037)   &      & ()   &      &        & (0.059)&        &       & \\
C_t   & 0    & 0    & 0.681    & 0.28 &C_t   & 0      &  0     &  2.130 &       & \\
  &      &      & (0.070)  & ()   &      &        &        & (0.107)&       & \\
\hline
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{11}{l}{Parameter Estimates Subset 2 and 3} \\
\cline{1-11}
A     & L_{t-1} & S_{t-1} & C_{t-1}  & \mu & Q&L_{t}& S_{t}  & C_{t}  & \lambda & H   \\
\hline
L_t   & 1.031    & 0    & 0    & 6.02 & L_t  & 0.077  & 0      & 0 &  0.123&  0.017\\
  & ()       &      &      & ()   &      &(0.021) &        &        &(0.005)& (0.002)\\
S_t   & 0    & 0.910    & 0    & -0.02& S_t  & 0      & 0.720  & 0      &       &\\
  &      & (0.037)   &      & ()   &      &        & (0.059)&        &       & \\
C_t   & 0    & 0    & 0.681    & 0.28 &C_t   & 0      &  0     &  2.130 &       & \\
  &      &      & (0.070)  & ()   &      &        &        & (0.107)&       & \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Results of the Maximum Likelihood Estimation for splits 1--4}
\label{table:param3}
\end{table}  

\end{document}
```